# Sorting user defined array by string using selection sort in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I'm working on an assignment and I need to perform a binary search. But somehow I think I have problems in my selection sort. Here i have an user defined class called Record. It has the following properties:

```
class Record{
   String studentId;
   int assignment;
   int exam;
   int total;
   String grade;
}
```

I have getters for those properties. Now there is another class called **GradeBook** in which there is a an array of type **Record**. I manually loaded the record array via a method called loadFromTables as follows:

```
private void loadFromTables(){

    String[] students = {
        "S10","S20","S30","S40","S50", "S60", 
        "S08","S18","S28","S38","S48", "S58",
        "S06","S16","S26","S36","S46", "S56",
    };

    int[] assignment = {
        0, 10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 
        0, 10, 20, 30, 30, 40, 
        0, 10, 20, 30, 30, 40,
    };

    int[] exam = {
        0, 39, 44, 44, 54, 59, 
        1, 40, 45, 45, 55, 60, 
        2, 41, 46, 46, 56, 58, 
    };

    nrecords = students.length;
    gradeBook = new Record[nrecords];

    for (int i = 0; i < nrecords; i++ ) {

        int t = assignment[i] + exam[i];
        String g = calculateGrade(t);
        Record r = new Record( students[i], assignment[i], exam[i], t, g );
        gradeBook[i] = r;

    }


}
```

Now I want to do binary search to find a Record by the property **studentId**. But first I'd have to sort the **Record array**. I am told to use **Selection sort**. So, I do this and I think **this is where the problem lies** but I can't seem to figure out where..:

```
private void sortById(){

    //Selection Sort

    for(int i=0; i<nrecords-1; i++){

        int index = i;

        for(int j=i+1; j<nrecords; j++){

            if((gradeBook[index].studentId).compareTo(gradeBook[j].studentId) > 0){

                index = j;

            }

            Record temp =  gradeBook[i];
            gradeBook[i] = gradeBook[index];
            gradeBook[index] = temp;

        }

    }

}
```

And here is the code of binary search that I used although i think the binary search has been implemented correctly. Because i tried to do it with **bubble sort** and that did precisely what i wanted.

```
public Record find(String id){

    //Binary Search

    int low = 0;
    int high = nrecords - 1;
    Record record = null;

    while(low <= high){

        int mid = (high + low)/2;

        if(id.compareTo(gradeBook[mid].studentId) == 0){

            record = new Record(id, gradeBook[mid].assignment, gradeBook[mid].exam, gradeBook[mid].total, gradeBook[mid].grade);
            return record;

        }
        else if(id.compareTo(gradeBook[mid].studentId) > 0){

            low = mid + 1;

        }
        else if(id.compareTo(gradeBook[mid].studentId) < 0){

            high = mid - 1;

        }

    }

    return record;

}
```

Thanks in advance. I know the problem is in selection sort and it's eating my head. Appreciate your suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In selection sort, We first iterate through the sub-array and find the minimum element in the sub-array, then at last in each iteration, `Swap` the current and minimum element.

Problem in your code is here.

```
for(int j=i+1; j<nrecords; j++){

    if((gradeBook[index].studentId).compareTo(gradeBook[j].studentId) > 0){
            index = j;
    }

    Record temp =  gradeBook[i];
    gradeBook[i] = gradeBook[index];
    gradeBook[index] = temp;

}
```

You have found minimum element correctly but you are doing swaps in the iterations when you find a lexicographic smaller string than the current one. So in this loop, you just need to find the minimum element and `swap` operation should be done after execution of this loop.

**Corrected Code :**

```
private void sortById(){

    //Selection Sort

    for(int i=0; i<nrecords-1; i++){

        int index = i;

        for(int j=i+1; j<nrecords; j++){

            if((gradeBook[index].studentId).compareTo(gradeBook[j].studentId) > 0){

                index = j;

            }

            Record temp =  gradeBook[i];
            gradeBook[i] = gradeBook[index];
            gradeBook[index] = temp;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your corrected code contains the exact same thing as i had written, but the explanation was great. Thanks for that, marking it as answer! And it did solve my problem!